# Getting value from store selector in switchMap rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx, store

Actually, I have series steps and using switchMap in the effect of store. I would like to get value from store and retrieve it in switchMap. I tried as below but I was not able to get desired type value instead

**Actual result:**
var clients: any

**Expected results:**
clients should be of type getClients in the store.

In the code, I want to get value from withLatestFrom to switchMap in the next line of code. Commented in the code as TODO.

```
 @Effect()

  loadInResponse$ = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOAD_IN).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getNqResponse)),
  switchMap(([action, nq]) => {
  if (nq.httpStatus === 'OK') {
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getClients)), //TODO here
      switchMap(([action,clients]) => {              //TODO here
        var i;
        var result = [];
        console.log(clients);
        for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
          result[i] = clients.map(a => a.no);
        }
        return this.cinReuseService.InCall(result).pipe(
          switchMap(responseIn => [
            new fromActions.LoadInSuccess(responseIn),
            new fromActions.LoadService()
          ]),
          catchError(error => {
            let err: responseService = {
              status: "FALSE",
              message: error
            }
            return of(new fromActions.LoadInFail(err))
          })
        ) 
      })

  } else {
    let err: responseService = {
      status: "FALSE",
      message: nq.message
    }
    return of(new fromActions.LoadInFail(err))
  }
})
)
```

I am getting error as below:

*"You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Interable"*.

I would greatly appreciate for the help. Thank you!

Comment: You cant just add if in between rxjs operator. Why dont you split your effect in multiple effects? What I would do is dispatch an action inside the if and the else that would help you deal with the problem, so you would have a parent effect that check the status and if the status is ok then dispatch an action that does what is inside the if and if its not ok dispatch an action that does what is inside the else.

Comment: I am new to rxjs if you can give me direction. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer because it made no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong, as soon as you enter the switchMap function, you are no longer in an observable so thats why you had problems related to the withLatestFrom. SwitchMap also return an array and create an observable which means you dont have to use of().
What I said in the comment would look like this:
You need a new effect and a new action(loadOk). I dont know if the action need a parameter because its kinda hard to follow.

```
@Effect()
loadInResponse$ = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOAD_IN).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getNqResponse)),
    switchMap(([action, nq]) => {
        if (nq.httpStatus === 'OK') {
            return [new formActions.LoadOk];
        } else {
            let err: responseService = {
                status: "FALSE",
                message: nq.message
            };
            return [new fromActions.LoadInFail(err)];
        }
    })


@Effect() okResponse = this.actions.ofType(fromActions.LOAD_OK).pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getClients)),
    switchMap(([action,clients]) => this.cinReuseService.InCall(this.result(clients))),
    switchMap(responseIn => [
                new fromActions.LoadInSuccess(responseIn),
                new fromActions.LoadService()
    ]),
    catchError(error => {
        let err: responseService = {
            status: "FALSE",
            message: error
        }
        return [new fromActions.LoadInFail(err)];
    })
)

result(clients: []): [] {
    var i;
    var result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        result[i] = clients.map(a => a.no);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The code runs fine but I am getting the same error as: "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Interable". @ukn

Comment: When I put the console.log before return [new formActions.LoadOk];. It does not print.

Comment: I added switchMap(()=>{ return [new fromActions.LoadOk()]; in between if condition because it was complaining to your code about the data type.

Comment: You cant add a switchMap randomly and expect it to work. You know you can just debug it in your browser to see if it reaches the if.

Comment: It does not reach there. I debuged it.

Comment: If it doesnt reach the if, it means your selector is not returning what you think. Are you sure your effect is even reached?

Comment: Ok I think I found the issue. @ukn. It is in my code